# How do I update my answer message coding?

Tags: python

I am doing a coding where I need to program different math flashcards and the user has to answer them. But when answering them, the message keeps saying the same number and not updating the new numbers that it is supposed to get.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint

def clicked():
    messagebox.showinfo('Rules of the Game', '1. You are going to be provided with basic arithmetic (Adding, Subtracting, Multiplying)'
    '\n2. You are going to answer them'
    '\n3. Based on the answer you gave, it will keep track of the correct and incorrect answers including how many in total you have answered')                       

root = Tk()
root.title('Math Flash Cards')
root.geometry('900x500')

Title = Label(root, text="Title", font=('Arial', 30))
Title.grid(row = 0, column = 4)

Rule_btn = Button(root, text="Click Here for Rules", font=('Arial'), command=clicked)
Rule_btn.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

#Create random flashcard numbers
def math_random():
    global nums
    number_1 = randint(1,10)
    number_2 = randint(1,10)

    add_1.configure(text = number_1)
    add_2.configure(text = number_2)
    

def answer_add():
    answers = number_1 + number_2
    if int(add_ans.get()) == answers:
        response = 'Correct ' + str(number_1) + ' + ' + str(number_2) + ' = ' + str(answers)
    elif int(add_ans.get()) != answers:
        response =  'Wrong! ' + str(number_1) + ' - ' + str(number_2) + ' = ' + str(answers)
    answer_message.config(text = response)
    add_ans.delete(0, 'end')
    math_random()
    

global nums
number_1 = randint(1,10)
number_2 = randint(1,10)


global add_1
global add_2
add_1 = Label(root, text='+', font=('Arial', 20))
add_2 = Label(root, text='+', font=('Arial', 20))
math_operator = Label(root, text='+', font=('Arial', 20))


add_1.grid(row = 5, column = 3)
math_operator.grid(row = 5, column = 4)
add_2.grid(row = 5, column = 5)


add_1.configure(text = number_1)
add_2.configure(text = number_2)


global add_ans
add_ans = Entry(root, font = ('Arial', 14))
add_ans.grid(row = 7, column = 4)
add_ans_btn = Button(root, text ='Click', font = ('Arial'), command= answer_add)
add_ans_btn.grid(row = 7, column = 5)

global answer_message
answer_message = Label(root, text='Type you answer with the provided space above', font=('Arial'))
answer_message.grid(row = 10, column = 4)
```

What should I do to make it update? I kept making changes to the code, but it is not changing when the numbers are changing.